# How to remain the delegate method being called in native instead of react native firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

**PROBLEM**

I'm setting up Firebase cloud messaging on my app run on Native(ios & android) which hybrid with React Native on a module. I'm facing problem in receiving message delegate method in iOS native is not call if I use React-Native-Firebase library in react native.

**DESCRIPTION**

This is happened when I have react-native-firebase on my react-native module. It seems like the delegate methods in native being hijacked by the listener in react-native.

I have tried turned off the react-native module and run the app, the native delegate method would be called once I sent the test notification from Firebase.

**EXPECTATION**

I expect both delegate method in iOS native and react-native will be called.

The main ideal is I would like both iOS native and react-native can received the notification and proceed the different action accordingly.

Thanks!